# Select * from this week

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with data and a column named 'week'. Everytime an user post something to the database, this is added to the column 'week':

```
$week = Date('W');
```

So everything inserted in this week have the number '13' in the week-column. Now I would like a query that select everything from this week and post on my site, so I wrote a variable like the one above and wrote:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = $week';
```

But it echos an error: `Unknown column '$week' in 'where clause'.`

It works fine, if I write `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = 13;` but I would like it to automatically select the current week number.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful to SQL Injection and
change this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = $week';
```

in

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = '.$week;
```

Comment: How would this protect against [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: This won't protect from SQL Injection, but that's the way if you don't want to use prepared statements

Comment: That did it! Thank you! :) I will take a look at prepared statements!

Comment: No worries.Yeah that's a more sopisthicated way to accomplish this

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply do

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = WEEK(NOW())";
```

Just a note: `SELECT *` is not good and very bad practice. Select only what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use double quotes for the string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = $week";
```

If not, $week will not substituted.

You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: you guys  forgot the '   '  for week '$week'

Comment: @Gert Looks like the `week` column is an integer so the quotes are not necessary

Comment: @Gert: No. It Looks like week is of type int not of type character

Answer (score 0):

Please use this, it is safer vs SQL injection:

```
$week = $mysqli->escape_string($week);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE week = '" . $week . "'";

$retval = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

You need the mysqli object set as connection to your database for this to work. After that you can fetch the rows from $retval.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date column is an actual MySQL date column:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```